# Why are circular unit vectors often defined as $\hat{\mathbf e}_\pm = \mp (\hat{\mathbf e}_x \pm i \hat{\mathbf e}_y)/\sqrt{2}$

Tags: conventions, notation, spherical-harmonics

When dealing with circular polarizations, spherical harmonics, and generally with any vector-valued rotationally-invariant quantity, it is often a requirement to define complex-valued unit vectors of the form $(1,i,0)$ and $(1,-i,0)$, which have the nice property that under a rotation they go to themselves times a complex phase.

However, many resources, especially the ones with a serious and systematic stance, use a different sign convention, and they define
$$
\newcommand{\ue}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{e}}_{#1}}
\ue\pm= \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\ue x \pm i \ue y\big),$$
with a global sign up front.
This is relatively counter-intuitive to me, but it sees a fair amount of use [see [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0761), [2](http://info.phys.unm.edu/~ideutsch/Classes/Phys531F11/SphericalTensors.pdf), [3](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys5250/phys5250_fa14/lecnotes.2014-11-03.Spherical_Tensors.html), [4](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~gleeson/ElectricityMagnetismAppendixE.pdf) for examples], so I imagine there must be some reason for this convention.

**In what way does this sign convention simplify things?** This isn't the kind of thing you'd do at random, by just introducing gratuitous complexity on a cornerstone formula that should be as simple as possible, so I imagine it's there to reduce complexity elsewhere. What exactly is that 'elsewhere'?

---

<sup>For the benefit of sanity on this thread, `\ue{x}` has been defined to produce $\ue{x}$.</sup>

Comment: Related, I think: [Why do we need the Condon-Shortley phase in spherical harmonics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301688/why-do-we-need-the-condon-shortley-phase-in-spherical-harmonics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One answer, connecting he antisymmetry of the wedge product and the (Lie) commutator, is through the Wigner-Eckart theorem.
Let 
$$
\hat T_{10}=\hat L_z\, \qquad \hat T_{1\pm 1}=\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(\hat L_x\pm i \hat L_y\right)=\mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat L_{\pm}
$$
Then the matrix elements
$$
\langle jm'\vert \hat T_{1\mu}\vert jm\rangle=\langle jm;1\mu\vert jm'\rangle
\sqrt{j(j+1)}
$$
where $\langle jm;1\mu\vert jm'\rangle$ is a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient.  Basically, the $-$ sign is required to define $\hat T_{11}$ as the correct $+1$ component of the tensor operator.

The connection with the wedge product is so that 
$$
\newcommand{\ue}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{e}}_{#1}}
[\hat T_{1k},\hat T_{1m}]\leftrightarrow \ue{k}\wedge \ue{m} 
$$
and indeed in some textbooks the commutator $[\hat T_{1k},\hat T_{1m}]$ is written as $\hat T_{1k}\wedge \hat T_{1m}$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ue}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{e}}_{#1}}$
If you define $\ue\pm$ as

$$\ue\pm= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\ue x \pm \mathrm{i} \ue y\big)$$

you get

$$\ue+\wedge \ue- = -\mathrm{i}\ue z.$$

If, instead, you define

$$\ue+ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\ue x + \mathrm{i} \ue y\big)$$

and

$$\ue- = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(\ue x - \mathrm{i} \ue y\big),$$

the cross product becomes

$$\ue+\wedge \ue- = \mathrm{i}\ue z.$$

Therefore, in the former case, $(\ue+,\ue-,\mathrm{i}{\ue z})$ has the same orientation of $(\ue x,\ue y, \ue z)$, whereas in the latter the orientation is preserved by $(\ue -,\ue +, \mathrm{i}\ue z)$.

Is there any reason to prefer one orientation with respect to the other? I would say no, it's probably just a matter of tradition.