# Pauli Matrix's eigenvector formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, definition, notation

In [the Wikipedia page for the Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues), there is a list of the eigenvectors of the Pauli matrices.

Notice at $\sigma_y$, it's eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \pm i \end{pmatrix}$ but not  $\begin{pmatrix} \pm i\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, same for $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$.

By which formalism or customs stated that Pauli matrices' eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \pm i \end{pmatrix}$ but not  $\begin{pmatrix} \pm i\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: They are equal, modulo an $i$ or two. People liked the 1 up top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to encode vectors on the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) sets the first component as a positive real number, and this convention is influenced by that.

But that's about it: it is a convention, and you're welcome to change it if there's a specific reason why that would suit your purposes better.

However, if there *isn't* a well-defined reason why it's better for you in some measure, then I would advice against trying to buck this convention: the only thing that it's going to achieve is that a good fraction of your readers is going to waste time wondering why the phase convention on your eigenbases has been chosen in a non-standard way, and you want your readers' attention to be focused on what you want to say instead of on your notation. The positive-first-component is just a part of the shared language that makes it easier to communicate clearly about the content; there's no good reason to make one choice over others (unlike in [other domains](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301688/why-do-we-need-the-condon-shortley-phase-in-spherical-harmonics)) but having a common choice that breaks that degeneracy takes that uncertainty out and leaves more room for the physics.